# cannot get color schemes to display correctly in neovim

Tags: neovim, plugin-solarized

I've been fiddling with neovim color schemes for a while now, and cannot make them look same as on previews.

I'm using terminal.app on osx, and thought it was 256 color cap problem, so I moved to iterm2 which has true color support - while it improved some things, color schemes are nowhere near to screenshots I see!

[image]

this is how solarized theme looks in iterm2 + neovim

[image]

this is nothing close to https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized screenshots!

I've used google foo but without success, surely there is a way to get colors right. Any ideas?

```
  "*****************************************************************************
"" Plug install packages
"*****************************************************************************

" Specify a directory for plugins
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')

Plug 'tomasr/molokai'
Plug 'dracula/vim'
Plug 'justb3a/vim-smarties'
Plug 'tyrannicaltoucan/vim-quantum' " let g:quantum_black = 1
Plug 'mhartington/oceanic-next'
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
" Plug 'vim-scripts/CSApprox'
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace'
Plug 'editorconfig/editorconfig-vim'
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'valloric/matchtagalways'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

"*****************************************************************************
"" Visual Settings
"*****************************************************************************
set number
set ruler
set nowrap

let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_TRUE_COLOR=1 
set termguicolors " unfortunately doesn't work in terminal.app - needs true color support, like iterm2 but it lags and diff in visuals is not that much so sticking to terminal.app for now

set background=dark
colorscheme solarized

"*****************************************************************************
"" NERDTree config
"*****************************************************************************

" open NERDTree automatically when vim starts up on opening a directory
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in") | exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0] | wincmd p | ene | endif

" keep focus on NERDTree when opening a directory
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p

" close vim if the only window left open is a NERDTree
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif

"*****************************************************************************
"" Optimizations
"*****************************************************************************

set lazyredraw

let g:python_host_skip_check = 1
let g:python3_host_skip_check = 1

"*****************************************************************************
"" syntastic
"*****************************************************************************

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

"*****************************************************************************
"" yank and cut to osx clipboard
"*****************************************************************************

noremap YY "+y<CR>
noremap XX "+x<CR>

"*****************************************************************************
"" indent
"*****************************************************************************

" tabs
set listchars=tab:˗\ ,eol:¬
set list

" spaces
let g:indentLine_enabled = 1
let g:indentLine_concealcursor = 0
let g:indentLine_char = '·'
let g:indentLine_faster = 1

set tabstop=2

"*****************************************************************************
"" matchtagalways
"*****************************************************************************

let g:mta_filetypes = { 'html' : 1, 'xhtml' : 1, 'xml' : 1, 'jinja' : 1, 'php': 1 }

"*****************************************************************************
"" ctrlp
"*****************************************************************************

set wildignore+=*.o,*.obj,.git,*.rbc,*.pyc,__pycache__
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = '\v[\/](node_modules|target|dist)|(\.(swp|tox|ico|git|hg|svn))$'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to set iTerm2's colorscheme to `Solarized Dark`. This only really helps if you want solarized *everywhere*.

- Open iTerm2
- Go to Settings(>iTerm2>Preferences or Cmd-,)
- Go to Profiles tab
- Go to Colors sub-tab
- Click `Color presets...` in the bottom right and choose `Solarized Dark`(or light)

Comment: yeah but I've trouble with all themes I find on vimcolors.com which is a bummer/